# Is there a tool that creates a basic HTML interface from an ABI?

Tags: web3js, dapps, dapp-development, frontend

I am looking for a tool that builds a basic interface for a contract so that I can use this generated HTML as a starting point to build the front end.

I am aware that Mist, https://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/ and http://tgerring.github.io/abi2html-js/# all do this but I haven't found a way to extract the HTML/Java script.

Answer (score 7):

Martin - have you tried Bloc? https://github.com/blockapps/bloc

It does a very basic auto-generated UI

Comment: Link to Bloc is dead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the MIX IDE which can make it easy to build a mock UI along with a contract and the ability to debug the contract.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mix:-The-DApp-IDE

Comment: What part of creating the HTML does Mix automate? In the link it seems that everything needs to be done manually, quote: "Now select index.html and enter the following html code"

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to quickly test Smart Contract, ETH 95 can be used.

[ETH 95](https://eth95.dev/) is a generic tool to test the smart contract.
You can import contract ABI and deployed contract address on public network and use MetaMask to interact with the Smart Contract.

ETH 95 is an Open Source UI avaialble under MIT License. It provides an instant retro UI to test any of the smart contract functionality. [GITHUB](https://github.com/adrianmcli/eth95)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: click on ETH 95 url above to visit the tool in browser.